# Add element to sublist of a list

Tags: haskell

I have the following code:

```
let numbers = [[1],[2],[3],[4]]
```

I want to append "3" to the sublist at index 2 of the list (`[3]`), like this:

```
(numbers !! 2) ++ [3]
```

to get this:

```
numbers = [[1],[2],[3,3],[4]]
```

But Im very confused :P Any idea?

Comment: Updating only a part of a large structure is what _lenses_ are for. But lenses are fairly advanced. I'd recommend you write you own custom update function, something like `update :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]`. This should be implementable by recursion.

Comment: Don't think of it as updating the list. Instead, think of it as computing a new list based on the old list, the position, and the value to append.

Answer (score 1):

other way is by take and drop

```
take 2 numbers ++[(numbers !! 2) ++ [3]]++drop 3 numbers
```

1. take the first 2 array --> [[1],[2]]
2. find the target array and [3] to it --> [[3]++[3]] returns [[3,3]]
3. drop 3 first array --> [[4]]

   [[1],[2]] ++ [[3]++[3]] ++ [[4]] = [[1],[2],[3,3],[4]]

Answer (score 0):

If writing the recursive update function is difficult for you, you can convert your list structure to a synthetic indexed array with `zip`

```
zip [0..] [[1],[2],[3],[4]]
```

and write your concat version based on the index as you do in other languages with indexed arrays

```
appendAt n a = map (\(i,x) -> if i==n then x++[a] else x) . zip [0..]
```

then,

```
appendAt 2 3 numbers
```

wll give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

As chi already commented, the best way to do such an *update on part of a structure* in modern Haskell is with *lense combinators*, specifically, [`ix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.15.4/docs/Control-Lens-At.html#v:ix):

```
Prelude Control.Lens> let numbers = [[1],[2],[3],[4]]
Prelude Control.Lens> numbers & ix 2 %~ (++[3])
[[1],[2],[3,3],[4]]
```

(Don't be scared of lenses. The main `lens` package is huge and dependency-heavy, but most of its killer features, including `ix`, are also covered by the compatible and much smaller [`microlens` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/microlens).)

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, in Haskell you don't normally modify a data structure in place.  Instead, you break it apart, introduce your modification, and put it back together to create a new data structure that incorporates the change.

For making changes to a specific list element, I've found the `splitAt` function to be useful for breaking apart lists.  For example, if you split your list at index 2, it produces the following pair of lists:

```
> splitAt 2 numbers
( [[1],[2]] , [[3],[4]] )  -- spaces added to make it clearer
```

Note that the element you want to change is the first element of the second list.  You can use Haskell's pattern matching to process this pair conveniently:

```
> let (a, x:b) = splitAt 2 numbers
> a          -- initial part of list
[[1],[2]]
> x          -- element to change
[3]
> b          -- rest of list
[[4]]
> a ++ x : b              -- put list back together unchanged
[[1],[2],[3],[4]]
> a ++ (x ++ [3]) : b     -- put list together w/ modification
[[1],[2],[3,3],[4]]
```

If this was turned into a Haskell function, it would probably look like:

```
appendSublist :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]] -> [[a]]
appendSublist idx y lst
  = let (a, x:b) = splitAt idx lst
    in  a ++ (x ++ y) : b
```

which you'd use like this:

```
> appendSublist 2 [3] numbers
[[1],[2],[3,3],[4]]
```

This basic pattern:

```
let (a, x:b) = splitAt idx lst in a ++ (...replacement for x...) : b
```

is worth memorizing, since it's pretty useful.

Eventually, you'll probably want to learn to use the `lens` library for this kind of thing.  Lenses are more concise and more flexible (i.e., work for all sorts of things, not just specific list items), but there's a pretty big learning curve, as you can maybe guess from @leftaroundabout's answer.